# how to use animate.css

Tags: html, css, animation, css-selectors

I'm trying to animate a div with animate.css function, fadeInUp, but it doesn't work.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="grid mt-4 claim animate__animated animate__fadeInUp"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why does your `div` not have a covering `</div>`? Your code works well. Try this - `<div class="grid mt-4 claim animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">test</div>`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov It does on my IDE, i'll edit it immediately

Comment: I just checked your code here in the SO snippet. And the code works well for me.

Comment: Well I don't know why that is but its not working on my end

Comment: I made a snippet. Take a look. The text works on the `fadeInUp` principle.

Comment: Perhaps the animation is working on your project, but you just do not have time to see this animation ?!

Comment: I checked it again and it worked just as I reloaded the page. and yes I have decreased to animation speed to 2secs and its still working only after I hit the refresh button

Answer (score 2):

To **delay** animation, you need to use rule `animation-delay`. Like this:

```css
div {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />

<div class="grid mt-4 claim animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">test</div>
```

Comment: I rechecked it and it worked, only problem is that it only works immediately I refresh the page. I tried decreasing the speed to 2 seconds but nothing changed

Comment: Did you mean a 2 second delay? How do you set the speed to 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes, 2 second delay. I did that by adding 'animate__slow' class name to my div. Its a default function for animate.css . I saw the change but it still loaded just when I refreshed the page instead of after

Comment: The fact is that the `animate__slow` class is responsible for the **duration** of the animation, but not for the delay. You need a class with rule `animation-delay`.

Comment: I updated my answer to add `animation-delay`. Not 2 seconds, but 10 seconds. The animation starts after 10 seconds. Was such a result necessary?

Comment: I reduced the animation-delay to 2 seconds and it made it better. But I want to believe there is a better way to go about it, at least for the next time i'll use it

Comment: What does **"better way"** mean?

Comment: I just don't want to have to set animation-delay because the animation loads prematurely. I want to get to the root of the problem. You've been of immense help by the way.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. In this case, javascript will help you.

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello, I've not still come up with a suitable solution because the div I want animated is just under my front page, so if a user does not scroll down within the animation-delay period then he wouldn't get to see it. I wouldn't mind another suggestion feom you though.

Comment: Do you want to start animating div only when the user scrolls down to that div?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, I hope I didn't reply late though

Comment: This can only be done with javascript or jquery.